# Rails sorting on a virtual attribute generated from a model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, attr-accessor

I'm wondering about an awesome feature that could help a lot for sorting by model attributes or model virtual attributes.

I have a model called `Box` with some attributes. I'm showing on my index view a list of these boxes  with attributes and a status. This status is a bit special before it's generated and not record in my database (we are talking about real time status, there isn't any interest to record it).

I'm stuck with a sorting problem on this status.

My idea is the following:

```
#Box.rb
attr_accessor :status

def generate_status
  self.status = "awesome status" 
end

def status
  @status
end

def status=(val)
  @status = val
end
```

And I would like to access to this information on my controller

```
#BoxesController.rb
@boxes = Box.all #With my sort by virtual attribute status
```

I don't really want to do (before knowing how to sort the virtual attribute):

```
@boxes = Box.all
@boxes.each do |b|
  b.status = b.generate_status
end
```

Finally if it's possible I'll generalize this to all listed method on my model through a `Concern` I think. But to start this work I need to know if it's possible to sort by a virtual attribute

### Edit

Now I'm trying with this way in a scope:

```
#In a Concern included in my model
(["status"] rescue []).each do |method|
  scope "sort_by_#{method}", ->(order){
    if order.equal?("asc")
      self.where(nil).sort!{|a,b| a.send(method) <=> b.send(method)}
    else
      self.where(nil).sort!{|a,b| b.send(method) <=> a.send(method)}
    end
  }
end
```

There isn't any error but my elements aren't sorted.

Note that I called `["status"]` temporary because I'm currently trying to access to this variable declared on my Model (where my concern in included).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to sort by a virtual attribute using `ActiveRecord`, however, we can use `sort_by!` on the result.
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21

```
@boxes.sort_by! { |a,b| a.status <=> b.status }
```

To automatically set the status, you could use `after_find` callback.

```
#Box.rb
attr_accessor :status

after_find :generate_status

def generate_status
    self.status = 'awesome status`
end
```

Comment: `sort_by` isn't working. I have this error `NoMethodError: undefined method status' for nil:NilClass`. But `Box.all.map{|b| b.status}` is working. It seems that `b` variable on `sort_by` is nil.

Comment: Are you sure the array contains at least 2 items?